# GHC infers my ambiguous type to make constraint succeed

Tags: haskell, type-inference, typeclass

At my very early stages of implementing a type-level encoded tree, I came across GHC's peculiar behavior in its type inference when faced with ambiguous types when it involves type constraints. I wrote two AST nodes as below both of which can have their types checked via their implemented `Typed` type class instance:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

class Typed t where
  type T t

-- | A Literal node
newtype Lit a =
  Lit a

instance Typed (Lit a) where
  type T (Lit a) = a

-- | A Plus Node
data Plus a b =
  Plus a b

instance T a ~ T b => Typed (Plus a b) where
  type T (Plus a b) = T a
```

I then wrote the not type-checked `badPlus` function which performs no `Typed` instance check on the function arguments:

```hs
badPlus :: a -> b -> Plus a b
badPlus = Plus

badExample = Lit (1 :: Float) `badPlus` Lit 1 `badPlus` Lit 1 

>:i badExample
badExample :: Plus (Plus (Lit Float) (Lit Integer)) (Lit Integer)
```

As can be seen GHC inferred both un-annotated `(Lit 1)`s as (`Lit Integer`)s which were no surprise.
Now to my `goodPlus` where I add the `Typed` constraint on the signature:

```hs
goodPlus :: Typed (Plus a b) => a -> b -> Plus a b
goodPlus = Plus

goodExample = Lit (1 :: Float) `goodPlus` Lit 1 `goodPlus` Lit 1 

>:i goodExample
goodExample :: Plus (Plus (Lit Float) (Lit Float)) (Lit Float)
```

I was still expecting GHC to infer the two un-annotated types as `Integer` but, complain on `Couldn't match type 'Float' with 'Integer` yet, to my surprise (& delight) I saw that it marked them as `Float`s to make the constraint succeed.
My question is: Does GHC bend its type inference rules when constraints are involved? What is its defined procedure & priorities for type inference involving various type-signature constructs?

Comment: Possibly relevant: `warning: [-Wsimplifiable-class-constraints] • The constraint ‘Typed (Plus a b)’ matches instance (T a ~ T b) => Typed (Plus a b) This makes type inference for inner bindings fragile; either use MonoLocalBinds, or simplify it using the instance • In the type signature: goodPlus :: Typed (Plus a b) => a -> b -> Plus a b`

Comment: Note that `(1::Integer) + 2` and `(1.5 :: Double) + 2` both type check. In the first case, `2` is inferred to be an `Integer`. In the second case, we do _not_ get the same type for `2` and a type error, but instead Haskell makes `2 :: Double`. Essentially, the type of numeric literals is chosen to match the context. If the context poses no constraints, at the very end of the type inference process, a few `default` types are taken: that's why you get `1 :: Integer` in `badExample` -- that was picked as a default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what's going on here.  When GHC tries to typecheck the expression:

```
goodPlus (Lit (1 :: Float)) (Lit 1)
```

against the signature:

```
goodPlus :: Typed (Plus a b) => a -> b -> Plus a b
```

this results in the type equalities / constraints:

```
a ~ Lit Float
b ~ Lit n
Num n
Typed (Plus (Lit Float) (Lit n))
```

To solve this `Typed` constraint, GHC matches it against:

```
instance T a' ~ T b' => Typed (Plus a' b')
```

with:

```
a' ~ Lit Float
b' ~ Lit n
```

(Recall that constraints in instance definitions play no role in the matching process, so there's no problem matching to this instance.)  This results in an additional constraint:

```
T (Lit Float) ~ T (Lit n)                 -- (*)
```

However, `T` is an associated type family, and the instance for `Typed (Lit a'')` specialized to `Typed (Lit Float)` and `Typed (Lit n)` allow GHC to resolve these type functions:

```
T (Lit Float) ~ Float
T (Lit n) ~ n
```

But, this together with (*) above allow GHC to conclude `Float ~ n`.

So, the final typing is:

```
goodPlus (Lit (1 :: Float)) (Lit 1) :: Plus (Lit Float) (Lit Float)
```

and there's no ambiguity.

Comment: I see. So GHC does in fact generate its own  ```x ~ y``` constraints to help typechecking, and sees my ```T a ~ T b``` as an additional premise to help the process.

Comment: btw, for simplicity, I myself placed no ```Num a``` constraint in my implementation. Does GHC still place this constraint? If yes, why?

Comment: @shayan Numeric literals like `1` are polymorphic, and have type `Num n => n`. Using a numeric literal then introduces a `Num` constraint on its type.